# autosuggestion for integer not working in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using the Completion Suggesters as following.
There is an issue for numeric autosuggest

```
index : {
        "_index": "mysuggestors",
        "_type": "suggest",
        "_id": "584a4455",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Test  100AH 200 Title",
          "suggest": {
            "input": [
              "Test",
              "100AH",
              "200",
              "100",
              "200 Title",
              "Titl",
            ],
            "output": "Test  100AH 200 Title",
            "payload": {
              "id": "584a4455"
            },
            "weight": 10
          }
        }
      }

case 1.
autosuggest query : 

{"suggestions": {
  "text": "100",
  "completion": {"field": "suggest"}
}}

response :  empty response


case 2.
autosuggest query : 

{"suggestions": {
  "text": "100A",
  "completion": {"field": "suggest"}
}}

response : valid response


case 3.
autosuggest query : 

{"suggestions": {
  "text": "Tes",
  "completion": {"field": "suggest"}
}}

response : valid response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the analyzer for Completion Suggesters in your query.

By default the analyzer is Simple Analyzer which tokenize on only letters.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html

I believe you need Standard Analyzer-

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html

Comment: I am using Completion Suggesters

Comment: You can set the analyzer for Completion Suggesters in your query. By default the analyzer is Simple Analyzer which tokenize on only letters. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html#_definition_2. I believe you need Standard Analyzer- See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html

Comment: updated the answer. You can accept it so that others would know that it worked